# Git Convert All Remotes in a Repo from HTTPS to SSH

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Is there a command to programmatically convert **all** existing remotes on a repo from HTTPS to SSH?

For example, if I had a repo with a remote for GitHub, and another for GitLabs, and they both use HTTPS.

Comment: There is no single command that does that, but it should be relatively easy to script up something (possibly using your favorite text processing tools to directly edit `.git/config`, or using the `git config` command to retrieve and set values).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such command in git. But I agree with @larsks, you can use some small script, for instance with regular expression, to convert.